# Check if ParseUser exists before signing up

Tags: android, parse-server

I'm beginner on Android and I'm looking for a way on how can I check if a username exists already in Parse data class(User) in Android.

```
 btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(etmail.getText().toString());
                user.setPassword(etpwd.getEditableText().toString());
                user.put("nom_prenom", etname.getText().toString());
                user.put("tel", ettel.getText().toString());
                user.put("adresse", adresse.getText().toString());
                user.put("sexe", spsexs.getSelectedItem().toString());
                user.put("annee_naissance",spnaissance.getSelectedItem().toString());
                user.put("ville", spville.getSelectedItem().toString());
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            // Show a simple Toast message upon successful registration



                        } else {
                            alerte("Oupss!!", "Error..." + e.getMessage(), 0);

                        }
                    }


                    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        alerte("Succes", "Inscription terminée..", 1);
                    }
                });
```

I want to check if a username exist in parse : if it exist i want to show an error or a message ("username already taken").

Comment: I would suggest Cloud Code.  https://gist.github.com/cricket007/10001273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want do to this ? parse will do that itself for you.

You can track this using **ParseException**  object that you get in SignUpCallback's done method.

Try to get message of that ParseException.

Comment: but i want an error message 
in my case parse only don't add any user with a taken username but i have some error in my code : parse show the same message for all signup (successful and unsuccessful )

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you to check the ParseUI module, they have all those scenarios covered. Here is a snippet from ParseSignupFragment.java that does the validation:

```
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (isActivityDestroyed()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (e == null) {
                    loadingFinish();
                    signupSuccess();
                } else {
                    loadingFinish();
                    if (e != null) {
                        debugLog(getString(com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_parse_signup_failed) +
                                e.toString());
                        switch (e.getCode()) {
                            case ParseException.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
                                showToast(com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_invalid_email_toast);
                                break;
                            case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN:
                                showToast(com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_username_taken_toast);
                                break;
                            case ParseException.EMAIL_TAKEN:
                                showToast(com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_email_taken_toast);
                                break;
                            default:
                                showToast(com.parse.ui.R.string.com_parse_ui_signup_failed_unknown_toast);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: when i put (e.getcode) an error appear "Cannot resolve method getcode"

Comment: It's case-sensitive, check that you have e.getCode(). Besides, there is always e.getMessage(), which just give a string with the error description.